# How to write regular expression to match free email accounts?

Tags: php, regex, drupal, email-address

I'm trying to write a regular expression that checks if an email form field contains a free email address, with no luck.

Essentially I need to check if the email contains: `hotmail`, `yahoo`, `gmail` etc in the email field.

Comment: What do you have already? Post the code that doesn't work.

Comment: How good coverage do you need? There are thousands of free email providers on the Internet. What problem are you trying to solve with this detection?

Comment: I have a fixed list of domains that the client supplied, so only a handful of domains need to been checked.

Comment: @hixster: Why does the client need to filter free email accounts? Are they aware that the list contains only relatively few popular providers and is not complete? You might end up with tons of updates to this code and a client that is angry at you, because you didn't know the name of the biggest free email provider in Paraguay. This might end up on [http://thedailywtf.com]

Comment: It's only one validation on a contact form an they requested it work this way, despite my suggestions. They update the rules through the CMS, so it's no biggy. their only interested in preventing large providers google et al

Comment: This will come back to haunt you. Multiple times.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

regex would be sth like:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\.+]+@(gmail|yahoo|hotmail)(\.[a-z]{2,3}){1,2}
```

you can add all the other domains you want...
does it help you?

Comment: Obviously, the trick is how to get the list of 'all the other domains'.

Comment: @hixster, you *can* accept an answer, can't you? EDIT: I voted up your question, so now you have enough points to up-vote anyone.

Comment: -1: `myemail+@gmail.com` and I pass through your regular expression as using a paid service. Please people, don't forget `+` is a valid character in an email address.

Comment: Also, myemail@yahoo.co.uk is a valid alias for myemail@yahoo.com, so this will pass through the above regex as well.

Comment: @prometheus: `.co.uk` addresses are properly parsed by the above regex. Notice the `(\.[a-z]{2,3}){1,2}`... (dot)(2 to 3 letters)(repeated 1 or twice).

Comment: O.K how do I prevent .co.uk getting though as well?

Comment: @Tadeusz: I'm not sure you can find the domains automatically without a config list or sth like that. At least, I thought the question was more about the regex (cf. tag)
@Andrew: my bad... but the -1 is tough, sniff... :(

Comment: @hixster: haha, that's a slippery slope I mentioned before. You'll be worrying about free email in Paraguay just after dealing with UK. This problem cannot be solved reliably. How much money is your client willing to sink in annoying gmail users that might want to deal with the system?

Comment: @PierrOz: Exactly, there must be some manually created config list. And the config list always will be incomplete. An incomplete solution to a pointless problem specified by some Pointy-Haired-Boss.

Comment: @PierrOz: fact is, you don't even need to check what's before the @... Personally, I would simply go for `@(yahoo|google|hotmail)(\.[a-z]+)+$`

Comment: i'd drop the `(\.[a-z]+)` and change the entire expression to a simple `/\@(yahoo|google|hotmail)\./` so it can catch `.co.uk`

Answer (score 3):

```
/\@(hotmail|yahoo|gmail)\.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a big ol' disjunction?

i.e.

`yahoo\.com|googlemail\.com|blah\.net`

Pros: Easy to build, easy to read, explicit.

Cons: Maybe not the most efficient mechanism.

Comment: Actually if it were using Perl v5.10 it would be very efficient. That's because it becomes a trie.

Comment: Hmmm, not come across a 'trie' before - very interesting, thanks for the comment!!