# Drupal webform email field restrict free email

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I am using webform in drupal to capture users email address, but I want to restrict the user to enter free emails like gmail, yahoo, rediffmail etc. only corporate email should accepted. Can anybody please let me know how to do that? I got this [How to write regular expression to match free email accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318214/regular-expression-to-match-free-email-accounts) in stackoverflow but dont know how to implement in webform email field.

Comment: You are unlikely to be able to match all free email providers so shutting out a few is not going to be very effective.

Answer (score 0):

use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter). Well actually hook_form_FORM_ID_alter to set the '[element_validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html#element_validate)' property.

```
function example_data_form_user_register_alter(&$form,&$form_state) {
  $form['mail']['#element_validate'] = 'example_mail_validate';
}

function example_mail_validate($element, &$form_state) {
   if ( -- Whatever condition you like -- ) {
     form_error($element, t('Free email is not allowed.'));
   }
}
```